# Counting Subproblems in Dynamic Programming?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Taking a class on algorithms - trying to understand what is meant by the 'count of a subproblem' when discussing dynamic programming.

The scenario I'm faced with is as such:

An investor wants to invest 10 million dollars in
real estate. He can select properties from a list of 4 houses in 4 different cities.
He wants to purchase as much as possible, and he wants to maximize the expected profits that
he can get when he is going to sell the houses in the next year.

So I have four houses each with a value (the size of the problem) and expected profit next year (the value).

I'm being asked what is the count of subproblems here - but I'm confused by what this means.

If i make a dynamic programming table with V[i,w] then total number of possibilities is 11 * 5 (10 million, 4 houses, also taking into consideration 0,0) - 55

[image]

So am I interpreting this correctly as the subproblem count being 55?

Thanks,

Comment: 'count of **a** subproblem' is not the same as 'count of subproblems'. The former asks how many times each subproblem is encountered by the algorithm. That depends on the problem input. The latter is the size of the DP table, which is what you've calculated. Your calculation is correct if the prices are in whole millions, and you use an array for the DP table. You could also use a memoization dictionary to store subproblem results. In that case, the number of dictionary entries depends on the problem input.

Comment: You're going to have to ask your teacher what they meant. This is not standard terminology and your guess is as good as ours.